# SQL Split line during import - run INSRERT INTO twice for specific lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, union-all

let's assume a super-simplified data example:

```
ID    AKey   AVal
-----------------
1     AB     94
2     Q      48
3     Z      56
4     AB     12
5     T      77
...   ...    ...
```

I would like to split "AB" into separate lines "A" and "B" in my import script, where I typically do:

```
INSERT INTO MyNewTable
SELECT 
   SRC.ID as OldIDRef,
   SRC.AKey as NewKey,
   SRC.AVal as NewVal
FROM OldTable as SRC
```

So basically, I would like to duplicate the "AB" lines in the select and perform some calculations specific for this line (let's say divide AVal by 2)

The only solution I can think of would be someting like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyNewTable
SELECT 
   SRC.ID as OldIDRef,
   CASE SRC.AKey = 'BA' THEN SUBSTRING(SRC.AKey,1,1) END as NewKey,
   CASE SRC.AKey = 'BA' THEN SRC.AVal / 2 END as NewVal
FROM OldTable as SRC

UNION ALL

SELECT 
   SRC.ID as OldIDRef,
   SUBSTRING(SRC.AKey,2,1) as NewKey,
   SRC.AVal / 4 + 10 as NewVal
FROM OldTable as SRC
WHERE SRC.AKey = 'BA'
```

I will need such process more then few times in my imports, so I wonder, If I am not missing some simpler solution?

Comment: Are you OK the all Non-AB will be NULLs?

Comment: Is there a maximum length for Akey?

Comment: All nonAB - I'm afraid no, but they can be easily joined... I'm looking at your aswer bellow.

Comment: A maximum lenght - the key is nvarchar(50) and the split applies to two fixed phrases, each has two words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you are probably looking for an answer that can be scaled to N# of characters in the Key Length and one that aportions the new value to the number of keys that are split from it.  I would go with a recursive cte to pull it off.  With your sample data add another row with 3 characters in it like 'GHI' and run this code and see the results scale beyond just 2 characters.

```
;WITH cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
       Id
       ,AKey
       ,LEFT(AKey,1) AS NewAKey
       ,RIGHT(Akey,LEN(AKey) - 1) AS RemainingKey
       ,AVal
       ,1 AS [Level]
    FROM
       @Table

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       t.Id
       ,t.AKey
       ,LEFT(c.RemainingKey,1) AS NewAKey
       ,RIGHT(RemainingKey,LEN(RemainingKey) - 1) AS RemainingKey
       ,t.AVal
       ,c.[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
    FROM
       @Table t
       INNER JOIN cteRecursive c
       ON t.Id = c.Id
       AND LEN(c.RemainingKey) > 0
)

SELECT
    Id
    ,AKey AS OriginalAKey
    ,NewAKey
    ,AVal AS OriginalAVal
    ,AVal / 2.00 AS NewVal
    ,AVal / CAST(MAX([Level]) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) AS NewValAsPortionOfLevel
    ,AVal / CAST(LEN(AKey) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) AS NewValAsPortionOfKeyLength
FROM
    cteRecursive
```

Here is the Table variable I used if you want it

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), AKey VARCHAR(100), AVal INT)
INSERT INTO @Table (AKey, AVal)
VALUES ('AB',94),('Q',48),('Z',56),('AB',12),('T',77),('ghi',100)
```

If not splitting the key you can actually simplify the recursive cte and go that route.  By using `Level < LEN(AKey)` the recursion will stop at the right spot and you don't need any of the other string manipulations.

```
;WITH cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
       Id
       ,AKey
       ,AVal
       ,1 AS [Level]
    FROM
       @Table

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       t.Id
       ,t.AKey
       ,t.AVal
       ,c.[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
    FROM
       @Table t
       INNER JOIN cteRecursive c
       ON t.Id = c.Id
       AND c.[Level] < LEN(t.Akey)
)

SELECT
    Id
    ,AKey AS OriginalAKey
    ,AVal AS OriginalAVal
    ,AVal / 2.00 AS NewVal
    ,AVal / CAST(MAX([Level]) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) AS NewValAsPortionOfLevel
    ,AVal / CAST(LEN(AKey) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) AS NewValAsPortionOfKeyLength
FROM
    cteRecursive
```

And another technique if you have a very large dataset and don't want to use recursion, is you can build a Tally Table To Join on.  I would be curious to know which performs better. I actually have a permanent tally table for use in some of the record manipulation for ETL of data warehouse that I use, but you should probably use a temp table rather than a table variable too. Anyway, here is that method.

```
DECLARE @TallyTable AS TABLE (I INT)

DECLARE @MaxLen INT
SELECT @MaxLen = MAX(LEN(AKey)) FROM @Table

IF (@MaxLen > 0)
BEGIN
    WHILE @MaxLen > 0
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @TallyTable (I) VALUES (@MaxLen)
       SET @MaxLen -= 1
    END
END

SELECT
    *
    ,NewValueApportionedByLengthOfKey = CAST(AVal AS DECIMAL) / ISNULL(NULLIF(LEN(AKey),0),1)
FROM
    @Table t
    INNER JOIN @TallyTable tt
    ON LEN(t.AKey) >= tt.I
```

Note all of these methods assume AKey will never be NULL or 0 length but all are easily adapted to handle that should it be a need.

Comment: I misled you perhaps with the unnessesary SUBSTRING a bit, but overall the CTE logic can be applied and seems to be more feasible. I'll test both answers.

Comment: If you don't need to spilt the actual key and you just need to repeat the rows I would do that differently without the recursive cte  I would build a tally table based on the max length of the key and then join it on LEN of the key. if I get a chance between taking care of my son today i will try to write something like that here.

Comment: I added two methods that reflect no need to change the AKey value.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, here is the script, which works for given values and should be twice as fast as UNION ALL:

```
;WITH s1 as (
    SELECT ID, LEFT(AKey,1) as NewKey1, AVal / 2 as NewVal1
        , RIGHT(AKey,1) as NewKey2, AVal / 4 + 10 as NewVal2
        , AKey, AVal
    FROM Split)
SELECT ID as OldIDRef,
    CASE NKey.AKey WHEN 'A' THEN NewKey1 WHEN 'B' THEN NewKey2 ELSE s1.AKey END as NewKey,
    CASE NKey.AKey WHEN 'A' THEN NewVal1 WHEN 'B' THEN NewVal2 ELSE s1.AVal END as NewVal
FROM s1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 'A' as AKey UNION ALL SELECT 'B' UNION ALL SELECT NULL) as NKey 
ON NKey.AKey = NewKey1 or NKey.AKey = NewKey2 or (NKey.AKey is Null and not (NewKey1 = 'A' and NewKey2 = 'B') )
```

Comment: I think I misled you a bit, the Key does not have to be literally split. The data on some specific lines simply mix two things together and I have to perform some calculations over particular fields to split the two logical parts and put them into new database separately.